# Official pattern MEAN for JetBrains

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, webstorm, mean, jetbrains-ide

In webstorm I really like the template nodejs + expressjs. And I was very upset when I learned that there is no MEAN.
So I want to ask - does JetBrains template MEAN?  If not, which of the best generators?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `yo meanjs` (http://meanjs.org/generator.html) to generate a project skeleton and then open the generated application in WebStorm using File/Open. That's all

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/06/mean-stack-walkthrough-and-tips/) of the Jetbrains team talking about developing MEAN with the Jetbrains environment.